# Divs shifting after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey I am creating a chatbox where I refresh the `#users` and the `#chatbox` every 3 seconds. However, after being refreshed, both those divs are being shifted to the side. 
The refresh jquery code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var auto_refresh = setInterval(
        function(){
            $('#users').load('chat.php?_=' +Math.random()+' #users').fadeIn("slow");
            }, 3000); // refresh every 3000 milliseconds
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var auto_refresh2 = setInterval(
        function(){
            $('#chatbox').load('chat.php?_=' +Math.random()+' #chatbox').fadeIn("slow");
            }, 3000); // refresh every 3000 milliseconds
    </script>
```

Comment: can u create link in jsfiddle

Comment: some html and css would be usefull

Comment: Possible, on load you wrap loaded #chatbox in existed #chatbox

Comment: Alright, Ill create a JsFiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CFRUH/2/  Excuse the button on the bottom. It's working fine in the actual web browser

Comment: it seems depending on what is returned from your php scripts. maybe helpful if you provide them as well...

Comment: your jsfiddle need to attach external resources for adding messages.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CFRUH/5/ Here is the php for the users and chatbox

Comment: maximkou, what do you mean?